# Add multiple values that have the same employee name and then insert into the master again

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a three columns one with the employee name one with a cost and the last column is a blank Total. In the blank Total column I want to add the cost of all the duplicate names in the name column. I want to preserve the list of all the duplicate names but I only want the total of each employee to display in the row of the first time their name shows up.

In excel I used this formula and it accurately adds all values with the same name =SUMIF($A$1:$A$9,$A1,$B$1:$B$9) but I am having trouble only displaying the total value for each employee only in the row that their name first appears.

I may have to do a loop and I could not find my answers on regular excel formulas and I believe VBA may be the way to go.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Attached is a screenshot of what I want it to look like]

Answer (score 1):

No need for VBA:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you don't need VBA as =sumif function already gets you the solution, if you would like display the total value for each employee only in one row, you can just filter in 'Total' column and uncheck BLANKS.